# Get Appointment Body from a Room Resource Calendar

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508824.aspx), using a combination of FindItem and GetItem it should be possible to retrieve the notes section from an appointment.

This seems to work fine for a USER mailbox but fails when executed against a room resource mailbox.  Is there a way to retrieve the message body from from an appointment in a room resource mailbox?  Body.Value just returns null on a resource mailbox but the same code works fine on a user mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same on Exchange 2007 but on 2010 you are able to control "Resource Privacy Options". As default, it will remove a lot of information when adding appointments into a resource calendar, but it can be configured as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Try to toggle the "Comments from meeting requests" flag.